# Codigo Javascript no hace transiciones CSS

Tags: javascript, css

Hola buenas tengo un codigo javascript que abre una ventana, y tengo su css con las transiciones de fondo y todo pero no me las realiza..Alguien sabría decirme el porque?
Gracias

```js
function jmgModal(id1, data, ok, input) {
    data=data || {};
    id="modal-"+id1;
    
    if (document.getElementById(id)!=null) {
        //document.getElementById(id).remove();
        var divis  = document.getElementById(id);
         document.body.removeChild(divis);
    }
        var d=document.createElement("div");
         //d.style.visibility='visible';
        d.className="jmgmodal";
        d.id=id;
       
        var p=document.createElement("div");
        p.className="panel";
        p.id="panelp";
        //p.style.maxWidth ="450px";
        //p.style.maxHeight ="50px";
        var t=document.createElement("div");
        t.className="title";
        t.id="titlet";
       t.innerHTML=data.title;
        var cl=document.createElement("div");
        cl.className="close";
       // cl.innerHTML='&times;';
        cl.id="c1id";
        var ct=document.createElement("div");
        ct.className="content";
        ct.id="ct";
        ct.innerHTML=data.content;
        var f=document.createElement("div");
        f.className="footer";
        f.id="foot";
        
        var but=document.createElement("button");
        but.className="action";
        but.innerHTML=ok[0];
        but.addEventListener('click',function(ev) {
            try{
             var divisi  = document.getElementById(id);            
             document.body.removeChild(divisi);
            }catch(Error){alert(Error);}
        });
        
        f.appendChild(but);
        p.appendChild(t);p.appendChild(cl);p.appendChild(ct);p.appendChild(f);
        d.appendChild(p);
        document.body.appendChild(d);
    
   
}
```

```css
.jmgmodal {
        position: relative; margin: 0 auto;
        top:55%;left:35%; 
        width:70%;
        background: rgba(34,34,68,.8);
        box-sizing: content-box;
        visibility: visible; opacity: 1;
        transition: all .12s; z-index: 99;
}
.jmgmodal.visible {
        visibility: visible; opacity: 1;
}
.jmgmodal * {box-sizing: inherit}
.jmgmodal .panel {
        position: absolute; margin: 0 auto;
      /*  top:0;left:0;right:0;bottom:0;*/
        max-width: 450px; max-height: 50vh;
        background: white; border-radius: 10px;
        color: #ffffff; padding: 50px 0;
        transform: translateY(-25%);
        transition: all .12s;
}
.jmgmodal.nofooter .panel {
        padding: 50px 0 0 0;
}
.jmgmodal.visible .panel {
        transform: none;
}
.jmgmodal .title {
        position: absolute; top: 0;
        width: 100%; height: 50px;
        line-height: 50px;
        background:#2ECCFA;
        font-weight: bolder; padding: 0 2em;
        box-shadow: 2px 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,.6);
        border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        white-space: nowrap;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        overflow: hidden;
}
/* TEXTO DE CERRAR*/
.jmgmodal .panel .close {
        position: absolute; top: .25em; right: .75em;
        cursor: pointer; font-size: 25px;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -moz-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
        user-select: none;
}
.jmgmodal .panel .content {
        margin-left: 0px;
        font-family: verdana;
        font-size: 12px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%; overflow: auto;
        padding: 1em; box-sizing: border-box;
}
.jmgmodal .panel .content iframe:only-child {
        border: 0; width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
}
.jmgmodal .panel .content img:only-child {
        width: 100%; width: 100%;
}
.jmgmodal .panel .footer {
        position: absolute; bottom: 0;
        width: 100%; background: #2ECCFA;
        font-weight: bolder; padding: 0 .5em;
        box-shadow: 2px 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,.6);
        border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        white-space: nowrap;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        overflow: hidden;
        text-align: right;
}
.jmgmodal .panel .footer .action {
        border-radius: 10px; color: #000;
        background: #fff; border: 0;
        min-width: 80px; min-height: 35px;
        font-weight: bold; cursor: pointer;
        transition: all .12s;
}
.jmgmodal .panel .footer .action:hover {
        box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}
```

Comment: Hola Iron Man. ¿Has probado a depurar el código?

Comment: Todo lo que he podido..hah @lois6b

Comment: ¿Y has sacado algo en claro?

Comment: Que es posible que me falte algun action?? ex:but.className="action"; @lois6b

Comment: No tengo ni idea. Pero creo que a la pregunta le falta añadir toda la investigacion que hayas sacado en claro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si te fijas, el botón `#cerrar` sí tiene una transición, puesto que al pasar el mouse sobre él cambia su box-shadow (que no tiene antes de hacer hover).

La idea de las transiciones es que al cambiar una propiedad del estilo que tenga valores interpolables, el browser haga una iteración progresiva desde el valor inicial al final. En el siguiente ejemplo le puse `opacity:0` y `top:0` al modal, y al añadir la clase `visible` le doy `opacity: 1` y `top:15%`. Este clase se la agrego 500ms después de abrir el modal para que sea notorio que ocurre un cambio. Además le puse que las transiciones durasen 0.5 segundos en vez de 0.12, de nuevo para que aprecies el cambio.

De la manera como lo tenías puesto, no había transiciones puesto que en ningún momento manipulabas los estilos del modal salvo en el caso del botón.

Por otro lado, hay propiedades que no son transicionables. Por ejemplo `visibility` sólo puede ser `visible` y `hidden`. El browser no puede interpolar entre esos dos valores porque no hay nada intermedio como para proveer un efecto de animación.

```js
function jmgModal(id1, data, ok, input) {
    data=data || {};
    id="modal-"+id1;
    
    if (document.getElementById(id)!=null) {
        //document.getElementById(id).remove();
        var divis  = document.getElementById(id);
         document.body.removeChild(divis);
    }
        var d=document.createElement("div");
         //d.style.visibility='visible';
        d.className="jmgmodal";
        d.id=id;
       
        var p=document.createElement("div");
        p.className="panel";
        p.id="panelp";
        //p.style.maxWidth ="450px";
        //p.style.maxHeight ="50px";
        var t=document.createElement("div");
        t.className="title";
        t.id="titlet";
       t.innerHTML=data.title;
        var cl=document.createElement("div");
        cl.className="close";
       // cl.innerHTML='&times;';
        cl.id="c1id";
        var ct=document.createElement("div");
        ct.className="content";
        ct.id="ct";
        ct.innerHTML=data.content;
        var f=document.createElement("div");
        f.className="footer";
        f.id="foot";
        
        var but=document.createElement("button");
        but.className="action";
        but.innerHTML=ok[0];
        but.addEventListener('click',function(ev) {
            try{
             var divisi  = document.getElementById(id);            
             document.body.removeChild(divisi);
            }catch(Error){alert(Error);}
        });
        
        f.appendChild(but);
        p.appendChild(t);p.appendChild(cl);p.appendChild(ct);p.appendChild(f);
        d.appendChild(p);
        document.body.appendChild(d);
    
        window.setTimeout(function() {
          d.classList.add('visible');
        },100);
   
}

jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  jQuery('#abre_modal').on('click',function() {
  
    jmgModal(1,{title:'Mi Modal', content:'Este es el contenido del modal'},['cerrar']);
  
  });

});
```

```css
.jmgmodal {
        position: absolute; margin: 0 auto;
        top:0;left:35%; 
        width:70%;
        background: rgba(34,34,68,.8);
        box-sizing: content-box;
        visibility: visible; opacity: 0;
        transition: all .5s; z-index: 99;
}
.jmgmodal.visible {
        top:15%;
        opacity: 1;
}
.jmgmodal * {box-sizing: inherit}
.jmgmodal .panel {
        position: absolute; margin: 0 auto;
      /*  top:0;left:0;right:0;bottom:0;*/
        max-width: 450px; max-height: 50vh;
        background: white; border-radius: 10px;
        color: #ffffff; padding: 50px 0;
        transform: translateY(-25%);
        transition: all .12s;
}
.jmgmodal.nofooter .panel {
        padding: 50px 0 0 0;
}
.jmgmodal.visible .panel {
        transform: none;
}
.jmgmodal .title {
        position: absolute; top: 0;
        width: 100%; height: 50px;
        line-height: 50px;
        background:#2ECCFA;
        font-weight: bolder; padding: 0 2em;
        box-shadow: 2px 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,.6);
        border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        white-space: nowrap;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        overflow: hidden;
}
/* TEXTO DE CERRAR*/
.jmgmodal .panel .close {
        position: absolute; top: .25em; right: .75em;
        cursor: pointer; font-size: 25px;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -moz-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
        user-select: none;
}
.jmgmodal .panel .content {
        margin-left: 0px;
        color:#999;
        font-family: verdana;
        font-size: 12px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%; overflow: auto;
        padding: 1em; box-sizing: border-box;
}
.jmgmodal .panel .content iframe:only-child {
        border: 0; width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
}
.jmgmodal .panel .content img:only-child {
        width: 100%; width: 100%;
}
.jmgmodal .panel .footer {
        position: absolute; bottom: 0;
        width: 100%; background: #2ECCFA;
        font-weight: bolder; padding: 0 .5em;
        box-shadow: 2px 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,.6);
        border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        white-space: nowrap;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        overflow: hidden;
        text-align: right;
}
.jmgmodal .panel .footer .action {
        border-radius: 10px; color: #000;
        background: #fff; border: 0;
        min-width: 80px; min-height: 35px;
        font-weight: bold; cursor: pointer;
        transition: all .12s;
}
.jmgmodal .panel .footer .action:hover {
        box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="abre_modal">Abrir Modal</button>
```